# background-position not applied on IE

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

Setting a background position works on Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but not on IE 8-11. What's wrong here?

[DEMO on Dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/70063a92917abc48e335)

[DEMO on Webdevout](http://www.webdevout.net/test?021m)

```
.logo {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    background: url("layout/logo.png") center right no-repeat; /* fallback image */
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,...'), none; /* two bg to only use svg on supported browsers. IE 11 uses this image */
    background-position: center right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

UPDATE:

IE seems to ignore background positioning on SVG images. Here's a [WORKAROUND DEMO](http://www.webdevout.net/test?022R)

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: As described in the demo (including image) this is in IE 8, 9, 10 and 11

Comment: If you are trying to set the background image on the left, then try `background-position: left center;`

Comment: Have you tried `background-position-x`?

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi [that will break in Firefox.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=550426)

Comment: Background position is not compatible with IE8: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-background-offsets

Comment: @Huangism: I want it on the right, and "background-position: left center;" doesn't work either.

Comment: **background-size:20px  100%;** may be it will work check it

Comment: Ehm... thanks for the random guess... no it doesn't

Comment: @RolandSchütz on the right, your demo is displaying on the left for everything but IE. If you want it on the right then it's `right center` always x and y

Comment: My demo is saying that and it's positioning it on the right side.. anyway, I already found a workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way of doing this with a guaranty of cross-browser working is by  making the background image using a pattern and then set the attributes like `x`,`y`,`width` or `height` to position it as you want directly or later in jquery via the `attr` method for example: `$("#img1").attr("width","500");`

```
<defs>
   <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
       <image xlink:href="layout/logo.png" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
   </pattern>
</defs>
```

and set the pattern to fill the SVG path like this

```
<path fill="url(#img1)" id="my_svg" d="M5,50 l0,100 l100,0 l0,-100 l-100,0
     M215,100
     a50,50 0 1 1 -100,0 50,50 0 1 1 100,0
     M265,50
     l50,100 l-100,0 l50,-100
     z"/>
```

or you can set the background in this very way but in the CSS like this

```
#my_svg{
    fill:url(#img1);
}
```

There is also an alternative way which i ***do not*** recommend but may be the answer in some cases and that is the `transform="translate(x,y)"` for the image in pattern or the `patternTransform="translate(x,y)"` for the pattern which is quit like the css version if it..for example:

```
   <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100" patternTransform="translate(0,0)">
       <image xlink:href="layout/logo.png" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" transform="translate(0,0)" />
   </pattern>
```

anyway there is always good practice to know many different ways of doing something in our job to be able to survive ;-)